# Drag and drop from windows explorer to web browser

Tags: file, file-upload, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'd like in my web to let the user drag and drop a file instead of the tipical and boring **`<input type="file" />`**.

A perfect example is gmail. You can do EXACTLY what I want to attach files to a message.

Also I'd like it to be as cross-browser as posible (Chrome, Firefox, IE 6+, Opera and Safari).

Thanks!

It would be good that:

- Could be done using jQuery.
- Support multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). Made by the same folks who created TinyMCE. It does everything you want. It can grant up to 3 wishes, even if one of those wishes - <sub><sup>wait a minute...</sup></sub>

[*om nom nom* demo](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php)

Comment: @Bolu: the first link shows a feature table that answers your question. D&D with Plupload can use Google Gears, HTML5, or BrowserPlus.